# Siblings of parent except element clicked disappear in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

I am trying to fullscreen a **div#controls** when a button inside it is clicked and make all other **div#controls** with same parent, **div#buttons**, disappear.

**My HTML:**

```
           <div id="testpile" class="inner cover">
                <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
                    <div id="controls" class="col-md-4 rat">
                        <h1>Rationelt</h1>
                        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet, risus vel tincidunt sagittis, lorem risus faucibus mi, eget tincidunt ipsum sapien vel dolor. Mauris pulvinar leo feugiat, ultricies est ut, porta arcu.</p>
                        <a id="1" class="btn btn-group btn-default" role="button">Rationelt</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="controls" class="col-md-4 emo">
                        <h1>Emotionelt</h1>
                        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet, risus vel tincidunt sagittis, lorem risus faucibus mi, eget tincidunt ipsum sapien vel dolor. Mauris pulvinar leo feugiat, ultricies est ut, porta arcu.</p>
                        <a id="2" class="btn btn-group btn-default" role="button">Emotionelt</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="controls" class="col-md-4 per">
                        <h1>Personligt</h1>
                        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet, risus vel tincidunt sagittis, lorem risus faucibus mi, eget tincidunt ipsum sapien vel dolor. Mauris pulvinar leo feugiat, ultricies est ut, porta arcu.</p>
                        <a id="3" class="btn btn-group btn-default" role="button">Personligt</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**My jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btn-group').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('col-md-4 col-md-12');
        $(this).parent().siblings().toggleClass('col-md-4 col-md-0');
    });
</script>
```

I am quite sure that the problem I am having is that I have not succeeded in targeting the right div, but I have tried everything to solve it myself and sadly, haven't been able to.

Comment: Duplicate ID is invalid HTML.  Been this way since 1999 specs and still is https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute.  it MIGHT work sometimes,  but unpredictable results will occur that will be difficult to debug.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, it's a stupid mistake to make and I am glad I got that inside of my head and out of my script.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside of the control id being duplicated, simply toggle the display of the parents siblings to show/hide them on each button click:

```
 $('.btn-group').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().siblings().toggle();
 });
```

Comment: I must say that I did get the other code working, something like this: fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/5 I was just trying to tidy it up so I would not have to copy paste it 1 time for each button. Is it a stupid idea to do it like this? Also, thank you for your time. Also, I have removed the duplicated ID's, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting the right div, despite the invalid duplicate IDs. 
The use of `toggleClass` is the problem, especially after the first click, since it will toggle each class from its current state, which will give inconsistent results depending on which order the user clicks on each item -- you also appear to be toggling grid column declarations, which I'm not sure is what you intend?

Below I've changed your code to use `addClass` and `removeClass` explicitly (and have made 'hidden' still slightly visible so you can see the effect of subsequent clicks)

```js
$('.btn-group').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('hidden');
        $(this).parent().siblings().addClass('hidden');

    });
```

```css
.hidden {opacity:0.1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testpile" class="inner cover">
                <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
                    <div id="controls" class="col-md-4 rat">
                        <h1>Rationelt</h1>
                        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet, risus vel tincidunt sagittis, lorem risus faucibus mi, eget tincidunt ipsum sapien vel dolor. Mauris pulvinar leo feugiat, ultricies est ut, porta arcu.</p>
                        <a id="1" class="btn btn-group btn-default" role="button">Rationelt</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="controls" class="col-md-4 emo">
                        <h1>Emotionelt</h1>
                        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet, risus vel tincidunt sagittis, lorem risus faucibus mi, eget tincidunt ipsum sapien vel dolor. Mauris pulvinar leo feugiat, ultricies est ut, porta arcu.</p>
                        <a id="2" class="btn btn-group btn-default" role="button">Emotionelt</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="controls" class="col-md-4 per">
                        <h1>Personligt</h1>
                        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet, risus vel tincidunt sagittis, lorem risus faucibus mi, eget tincidunt ipsum sapien vel dolor. Mauris pulvinar leo feugiat, ultricies est ut, porta arcu.</p>
                        <a id="3" class="btn btn-group btn-default" role="button">Personligt</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I saw the "other classes" issue also, the OP probably will need to detect the length of the "hdden/not hidden" to apply the appropriate class (not part of the question though) nice way to show the effect BTW.

Comment: Ah, I haven't written code in quite some time, I forgot that I cannot use ID's more than once, thank you for reminding me. But I must say that I did get the other code working, something like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/5/
I was just trying to tidy it up so I would not have to copy paste it 1 time for each button. Is it a stupid idea to do it like this? Also, thank you for your time.

Comment: Toggling classes as in your fiddle will work fine for 2 elements, but with more than two the toggle state wouldn't always match what you need (if the user clicks A, that will toggle B and C off; then they click C, that'll end up toggling A off but B back on).   You've also switched to using explicit IDs inside the function, which would require copy-pasting code for more than a single button; the way you had it originally (`$(this).parent)...`) is better I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing anything to the siblings of the parent except just giving them a column class. From what I understand what you need to add is `.hide()` method. 
This will hide the divs that you want hidden.

Here is a link from the jquery api that will help you and give examples [link](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

remove that id `controls`. IDs should not repeat, use class there like;

```
<div class="controls col-md-4 rat">
```

and use JS like;

```
$('.btn-group').on('click', function() {
    $(".controls").hide();
    $(this).parents(".controls").show();
});
```